# MIME set to application/octet in AWS S3 when using binary buffer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, encoding, amazon-s3, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to make thumbnails of my photos on S3.
This is the flow:

1. Get the image from S3.
2. Make thumbnail from the `data.Body`.
3. Put the thumbnail on S3.

Here is the make thumbnail function:

```
function makeThumbnail(image) {
  var defer = q.defer();

  im.resize({
    srcData: image.Body,
    width: 256
  }, function (err, stdout) {
    if (err) {
      defer.reject(err);

    } else {
      image.Key.replace(/^images/, "thumbs");
      image.Body = new Buffer(stdout, 'binary');

      defer.resolve(image);
    }
  });

  return defer.promise;
}
```

The `image` object is of the form that S3 SDK expects to get it:

```
  var image = {
    Bucket: 'bucket name',
    Key: 'object key',
    Body: 'body',
    ContentType: 'image/png'
  };
```

Yet, when putting the thumbnail on S3, the MIME is set to `application/octet-stream` for some reason. When downloading the thumbnail it opens like any other picture, yet the browsers do not treat it like it's an image and that is a problem for me.

What causes this issue? and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code you've posted, where/when/how the ContentType gets set and how you're confirming that... but if it's really set to image/png when you actually do the upload, that should persist on the upload, be set in the S3 metadata, and returned to the browser as expected.

Comment: I'm hoping you're right but the documentation suggests that the content type can be derived from the content encoding which in my case is binary. Hence I thought that my explicit declaration of the content type is being overwritten once S3 sdk notices that the encoding is binary.

Comment: I'm quite certain that if a `Content-Type:` HTTP request header is sent to S3 when an object is uploaded, that value will be returned to the browser when requesting objects.  I've written my own libraries for AWS, don't use the SDKs very often, so I'm "only" really familiar with the behavior of the actual S3 service, not the SDK itself.  Not sure how deriving type from encoding would be really possible or desirable.  S3 itself just honors the directives that are sent -- no thinking happens.  (The console can figure out MIME types when you upload files there, but the console does that, not S3).

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [node-imagemagick.resize()](https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick#resizeoptions-callbackerr-stdout-stderr) says the default format is `jpg`. Maybe your output is not a `png` like you think.

We use the [im-resize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/im-resize) package and that contains input and output parameters, where we typically convert `.jpeg` images uploaded from a web form into `.png` output file. (We read from the file system after conversion, not stream buffers, just fyi).

Our code is something like this:

```
var resize = require('im-resize');
var metadata = require('im-metadata');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

metadata(data.params.file.path, {}, function(error, metadataResults) {
  //error checking

  var image = {
   //set from metadataResults
  };
  var output = {
    versions: [{
      //set as desired
    }]
   };

  resize(image, output, function(error, versions) {

   var filename = 'images/' + uuid.v4() + '.png'; //this was enough for us
   var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(versions[0].path);
          fileStream.on('error', function(err) {
           //handle error
          });
          fileStream.on('open', function() {
            var s3 = new AWS.S3();
            s3.putObject({
              Bucket: 'bucketname',
              Key: filename,
              Body: fileStream
            }, function(err) {
              //handle errors

//know the file has been saved to S3
//close up all the squiggly braces and return HTTP response or whatever
```

Comment: How would you set the S3 Body property to the result stream of the resize operation?

Comment: We used a different package that saved a file, which was turned into a filestream. The [AWS S3 docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) say `Body: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE' || streamObject,`, so as long as what you assign to `Body` is a `Buffer`, `string` or a `streamObject`, you should be in good shape. I do not know what `im.resize` returns as we did not use the package.